# group by a dataframe by values that are just less than a second off - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, pandas-groupby

Let's say i have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'dt':pd.to_datetime(['2018-12-10 16:35:34.246','2018-12-10 16:36:34.243','2018-12-10 16:38:34.216','2018-12-10 16:42:34.123']),'value':[1,2,3,4]})
>>> df
                       dt  value
0 2018-12-10 16:35:34.246      1
1 2018-12-10 16:36:34.243      2
2 2018-12-10 16:38:34.216      3
3 2018-12-10 16:42:34.123      4
>>>
```

I would like to group this dataframe by `'dt'` column, but i want to group it in a way that it thinks the values that are less than a second different are the same, after grouping those i would like to sum up the `'value'` column based on each group, and i want the dataframe two remain the same length, so the less than one second difference values would be all a duplicate value, i so far tried:

```
>>> df.groupby('dt',as_index=False)['value'].sum()
                       dt  value
0 2018-12-10 16:35:34.246      1
1 2018-12-10 16:36:34.243      2
2 2018-12-10 16:38:34.216      3
3 2018-12-10 16:42:34.123      4
>>>
```

But as you see, the dataframe didn't change because this groups by equivalent `'dt'` column values.

My desired output is:

```
                       dt  value
0 2018-12-10 16:35:34.246      3
1 2018-12-10 16:36:34.243      3
2 2018-12-10 16:38:34.216      3
3 2018-12-10 16:42:34.123      4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute force solution is to take the absolute difference between your `datetime` series and each `datetime` value, then compare against a threshold:

```
# data from @StephenCowley

threshold = pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)

df['val'] = [df.loc[(df['dt'] - t).abs() < threshold, 'value'].sum()
             for t in df['dt']]

print(df)

                       dt  value  val
0 2018-12-10 16:35:34.246      1    3
1 2018-12-10 16:35:34.243      2    3
2 2018-12-10 16:38:34.216      3    3
3 2018-12-10 16:42:34.123      4    4
```

Comment: Ah, saved me, thanks so much for this world-class solution, accepted and upvoted!!!

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you meant the first two to have the same minute value.)

I'm not sure how to do it with groupby, but here something with the same results:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'dt':pd.to_datetime(['2018-12-10 16:35:34.246',
                                      '2018-12-10 16:35:34.243',
                                      '2018-12-10 16:38:34.216',
                                      '2018-12-10 16:42:34.123']),
                                      'value':[1,2,3,4]})

            # Select the rows that are greater than a second less
            # And less than a second more
            # Get their value columns and sum them
df['val'] = [df[(df.dt>t-pd.Timedelta(seconds=1))&
                (df.dt<t+pd.Timedelta(seconds=1))]['value'].sum()
             for t in df.dt]

                       dt  value  val
0 2018-12-10 16:35:34.246      1    3
1 2018-12-10 16:35:34.243      2    3
2 2018-12-10 16:38:34.216      3    3
3 2018-12-10 16:42:34.123      4    4
```

---

As a sidenote, I looked into doing this same sort of thing with `groupby` but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work. You *can* pass a function into the `groupby` method. If you choose to go that route, note that the function is to take in indices of the Dataframe. Make's me think it would be hard to use the groupby since I don't know that one row can belong to multiple groups...