# Pandas groupby values with tiny difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe created by clause:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[29,31,48,51,66,64,68], 'B':[1.2,1.7,1.1,0.9,1.3,1.2,1.5]})`
it looks like this:

```
    A    B
0  29  1.2
1  31  1.7
2  48  1.1
3  51  0.9
4  66  1.3
5  64  1.2
6  68  1.5
```

I want to groupby 'A', not with exact values, but with abs less than 5. So what I want is like this:

```
    A    B  GroupId
0  29  1.2        1
1  31  1.7        1
2  48  1.1        2
3  51  0.9        2
4  66  1.3        3
5  64  1.2        3
6  68  1.5        3
```

How can I do?

I have find [group by a dataframe by values that are just less than a second off - pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700854/group-by-a-dataframe-by-values-that-are-just-less-than-a-second-off-pandas) is helpful, so I can use:
`df['sum'] = [df.loc[(df['A'] - t).abs() < 5, 'B'].sum() for t in df['A']]`
to get flowing:

```
    A    B  sum
0  29  1.2  2.9
1  31  1.7  2.9
2  48  1.1  2.0
3  51  0.9  2.0
4  66  1.3  4.0
5  64  1.2  4.0
6  68  1.5  4.0
```

then I can use 'sum' as ID to split this dataframe into different groups.
Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because values of column `A` are sorted get difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), compare for greater [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and add cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
#if necessary
df = df.sort_values('A')

df['GroupId'] = df.A.diff().gt(5).cumsum() + 1
print (df)
    A    B  GroupId
0  29  1.2        1
1  31  1.7        1
2  48  1.1        2
3  51  0.9        2
4  66  1.3        3
5  64  1.2        3
6  68  1.5        3
```

If possible some negative values and is necessary processing with absolute values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-29,31,-48,51,66,64,68], 'B':[1.2,1.7,1.1,0.9,1.3,1.2,1.5]})

df = df.assign(A1= df.A.abs()).sort_values('A1')
df['GroupId'] = df.A1.diff().gt(5).cumsum() + 1
print (df)
    A    B  A1  GroupId
0 -29  1.2  29        1
1  31  1.7  31        1
2 -48  1.1  48        2
3  51  0.9  51        2
5  64  1.2  64        3
4  66  1.3  66        3
6  68  1.5  68        3
```